# Relationships using same model classes for Ormlite & Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, ormlite

I have 2 api endpoints that return songs and artists. In my Android application, I hit these endpoints using Retrofit that uses a GsonConverter to give me back a list of either songs or artists objects depending on the endpoint. The objects are then persisted using Ormlite.

***Their json look like this***

**SONGS**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "foo", 
        year: 2000, 
        artist_id: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "bar", 
        year: 2002, 
        artist_id: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "foobar", 
        year: 2005, 
        artist_id: 2
    }
]
```

**ARTISTS**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "artist1", 
        country: "usa"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "artist2", 
        country: "spain"
    }
]
```

***The Java classes are as follows***

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "songs")
public class Song {

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String name; 

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField
    private Integer year; 

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private Integer artist_id; 
}


@DatabaseTable(tableName = "artists")
public class Artist {

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false)
    private Integer id; 

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String name; 

    @Expose
    @DatabaseField
    private String country; 
}
```

I am aware that in Ormlite to have relationships, the fields should be marked as "foreign" and also the type of that field should be the same as one of the classes persisted in the database. Since in my case, I get back only the "artist_id" in my songs json and not the whole json object for that artist, how can I implement relationships?

I believe that I am missing something very obvious here. It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction